# FFmpeg cannot find the file which is in the same directory as the python script

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Both of the input and output are in the folder, but python does not know where they are?

```
import subprocess
import pathlib

def convert_video_to_mp4(input_file, output_file):
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve())
ffmpeg_cmd = [
"ffmpeg"
"-i", input_file,
output_file
]

    try:
        subprocess.run(ffmpeg_cmd, check=True)
        print("Successfully converted")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Conversion failed!")

convert_video_to_mp4("Media.ts", "video.mp4")
```

First I was trying to convert a file on a website to mp4, that did not work, So I tried downloading the file to see if it would work and it still did not work.

Full Error

```
C:\Users\viofi\PycharmProjects\FFMPEGSERVER\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\viofi\PycharmProjects\FFMPEGSERVER\ffmpeg.py 
C:\Users\viofi\PycharmProjects\FFMPEGSERVER
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\viofi\PycharmProjects\FFMPEGSERVER\ffmpeg.py", line 21, in <module>
    convert_video_to_mp4("Media.ts", "video.mp4")
  File "C:\Users\viofi\PycharmProjects\FFMPEGSERVER\ffmpeg.py", line 15, in convert_video_to_mp4
    subprocess.run(ffmpeg_cmd, check=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Paths are relative to the process's working directory, not the location of the source code.

Comment: Also, note that it's the ffmpeg executable it can't find, not the .ts or .mp4 file; the `CreateProcess` call doesn't check if argument names refer to real files -- it only cares if the executable it's starting (and the libraries used by that executable) exist. Make sure `ffmpeg.exe` is in the `PATH` with which the script is being run (if it works in other contexts, maybe compare `os.environ["PATH"]` between those contexts).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try getting absolute path of the files?
If it's not that, you should check the current working directory of your Python script.